# Spring Boot run with or without Maven? JSPs are not resolved without

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot

When creating a Spring Boot application, in development environment, IntelliJ Idea creates a Run Configuration that is without Maven and it directly calls the static Main method with type of 'Spring Boot'.

When I run without Maven my JSP template files are not being resolved and I get the error page below.

When I run with Maven they are resolved but I can't debug. I am seeing some POM.xml configuration to be able to attach the debugger but then it debugs all the time even when I fire the app with Run and not Debug.

Should I run Boot app without Maven at all?
If I shouldn't, is this how the debug should be?
I feel something is wrong here...

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 16 08:53:54 GMT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I believe I see this error page because it tries to locate my index.jsp, can't find it, then tries for error.jsp and can't find that as well.

Comment: You SHOULDN'T run with Maven. Maven is just the build tool and you should not rely on it for execution.

Comment: @Adrian Shum, why not? I have seen a lot of times when IDEA classpath was different to the maven classpath. In this case, the result of the run by Maven is more accurate. Of course, you can run a binary file produced by Maven with the separate command, but what is wrong with running it by maven and consider it as the last step of the build process?

Comment: actually it depends on your definition of "running the application".  I was treating in general, when you finished all development etc and you deploy your application to run, you shouldn't rely on Maven doing so.  For debugging, as long as you can attach your IDE to the remote process, you can do debugging.  it shouldn't be something important for you to choose whether to run it with Maven or not...  Maybe I am still not clear about your question.

Comment: @AdrianShum this is development environment only. I'd package the application with Maven before running it, that's okay but I can't run the main's class directly because it can't find JSPs folder. So should I run with Maven or not during development? If I should run with Maven then debugging confused me. I think I should put these params to debugging run config shouldn't I? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html 
I put them into POM.xml then it was debugging every time I was running the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after doing more research it seems it is right to run Spring Boot application through the Main method directly rather than Maven in development environment.

Issue with JSPs are not being rendered without Maven was the Tomcat Jasper dependency's scope was `<scope>provided</scope>`, after changing that to "compiled" or "runtime" it started to work without maven. Interestingly when it was "provided" JSP rendering was only working with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different URLs like URL without or with the project (artifact) name. Maybe something wrong with the way how IDEA and maven deploy your war.
Also, it is possible to run the app from maven and then connect with the Remote run configuration of the IDEA to it. For this, you need to use mvnDebug instead of mvn - it is situated in the same folder as mvn ($MAVEN_HOME/bin/). And then you need to add Remote configuration to the IDEA with the port 8000 - it is default port.

Answer (score 0):

Try **re-importing Maven projects** first before running application from IntelliJ, or make it happen automatically when you change something in your `pom.xml` file (`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | Import Maven projects automatically`).

I use IntelliJ execution in my dev environment. What's more, if you would like to have features like *hot-reloading* for instance, consider using [devtools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) module shipped with Spring Boot which easily integrates with IntelliJ debug execution (just add `spring-boot-devtools` to your dependencies).